# Django — send 404 emails without referrer

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

From the [Django 1.5 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/):

> Django can also be configured to email errors about broken links (404 “page not found” errors). Django sends emails about 404 errors when:
>
> - `DEBUG` is `False`;
> - Your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting includes `django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware`.
>
> If those conditions are met, Django will email the users listed in the `MANAGERS` setting whenever your code raises a 404 and the request has a referer. (**It doesn’t bother to email for 404s that don’t have a referer** – those are usually just people typing in broken URLs or broken Web ‘bots).

I'm working on fixing up a web project that was poorly maintained by those that preceded me. One of the biggest problems is that there's no clear list of changed URIs, so there's a lot of people out there with bookmarks or links from pdfs/word docs that are likely leading going nowhere. Point is, I need a way to check for 404s with no referrers.

Is there a way check for 404s with no referrers using this Middleware? I'm open to other software or even solutions that don't use Django. It just needs to work.

Comment: I'd setup [sentry](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with [raven](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html) and make use of its excellent [404 middleware](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html#logging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just recycle Django's [middleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/common.py#L134) and remove the conditional check for the referrer in the header:

```
class BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        Send broken link emails for relevant 404 NOT FOUND responses.
        """
        if response.status_code == 404 and not settings.DEBUG:
            domain = request.get_host()
            path = request.get_full_path()
            referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'None')
            is_not_search_engine = '?' not in referer
            is_ignorable = self.is_ignorable_404(path)
            if is_not_search_engine and not is_ignorable:
                ua = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '<none>')
                ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '<none>')
                mail_managers(
                    "Broken link on %s" % domain,
                    "Referrer: %s\nRequested URL: %s\nUser agent: %s\nIP address: %s\n" % (referer, path, ua, ip),
                    fail_silently=True)
        return response

    def is_ignorable_404(self, uri):
        """
        Returns True if a 404 at the given URL *shouldn't* notify the site managers.
        """
        return any(pattern.search(uri) for pattern in settings.IGNORABLE_404_URLS)
```

Comment: This worked __almost__ perfectly — just had to remove the reference to `is_internal` in the call to `mail_managers()`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.