# Django 404 email notification

Tags: python, django, email, heroku, http-status-code-404

I want to get an email every time someone on my site gets a 404.

I added the following code to my settings.py file

```
DEBUG = False

MANAGERS = ADMINS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
]
```

The problem is that it just doesn't work.
After reading [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155350/django-send-404-emails-without-referrer) I decided to try to following

> I went to the file `django/middleware/common.py`

And made a change to the following class

```
class BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """Send broken link emails for relevant 404 NOT FOUND responses."""
        if response.status_code == 404 and not settings.DEBUG:
            domain = request.get_host()
            path = request.get_full_path()
            referer = request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", "")

            if not self.is_ignorable_request(request, path, domain, referer):
                ua = request.META.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT", "<none>")
                ip = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR", "<none>")
                mail_managers(
                    "Broken %slink on %s"
                    % (
                        (
                            "INTERNAL "
                            if self.is_internal_request(domain, referer)
                            else ""
                        ),
                        domain,
                    ),
                    "Referrer: %s\nRequested URL: %s\nUser agent: %s\n"
                    "IP address: %s\n" % (referer, path, ua, ip),
                    fail_silently=True,
                )
        return response
```

> FROM  `referer = request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", "")` To referer = request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", "None")

New class

```
class BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """Send broken link emails for relevant 404 NOT FOUND responses."""
        if response.status_code == 404 and not settings.DEBUG:
            domain = request.get_host()
            path = request.get_full_path()
            referer = request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", "None")

            if not self.is_ignorable_request(request, path, domain, referer):
                ua = request.META.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT", "<none>")
                ip = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR", "<none>")
                mail_managers(
                    "Broken %slink on %s"
                    % (
                        (
                            "INTERNAL "
                            if self.is_internal_request(domain, referer)
                            else ""
                        ),
                        domain,
                    ),
                    "Referrer: %s\nRequested URL: %s\nUser agent: %s\n"
                    "IP address: %s\n" % (referer, path, ua, ip),
                    fail_silently=True,
                )
        return response
```

**Now it works**

> However the problem is that I'm using heroku, and heroku does not give me access to the source files so I don't know how I can make this change.
> Heroku asks me what version of django I use and they just install it for me.
> My question is how do I get an email sent to me every times someone on my site gets a 404.